# Multiple render controller inside a twig

Tags: symfony

I have a twig calling

```
render(controller('Bundle:Controller:Method', { option: 'option' }))
```

16 times in a loop. It's working like intended but the problem is it's impacting the PHP memory usage drastically, at the point that the first few attempt from symfony to load the toolbar are returning a 404 error, but after few attempts the toolbar is found and loaded.

I've seen somewhere on the web that using a render controller calls the symfony workflow another time (so times 16 in my case).
So my question is the following : is there an alternative to render controller that is less memory heavy ?

The solution must be able to call few services and return a Response object with arguments.

Comment: Instead of having Twig call the controller-Action 16 times, try to call it directly from the initial action and hand the results over to twig.

Comment: The is good idea but in my case it would be too complicated to use this solution, i'll keep this as a last resort

Comment: Instead of using render, call a twig extension.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html Render is great for it's intended usages but, as you discovered, misusing it can cause serious performance problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do not offer to much information about why you need to do it in that way, them I just can give you some poor ideas.

The best solution is like @emanuel-oster say, get all the information before render the view. If you can't because are force to do it in the twig, them maybe you have the option of doing the loop first, create a new var with the objects id or something that allow you to call the controller just once with that information and do a single call them.

If that isn't an option neither, them I just think in manage to do it in the page load with some ajax request, since ajax call are asynchronous you could have a better user experience. Maybe show some waiting.. component, make all the request, and render all the components when each response came.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: the ajax part is very interesting, I didn't thought about it because I wanted to use twig so badly and it could actually do the trick, thanks